# iOS - Change "Test Details" of test flight build

Tags: ios, macos, testflight, apple-developer

I'm looking for a way/API to change "Test Details" of test flight builds:
[This field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyTct.png)

Someone that tried and figure this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use fastlane for beta distribution? The upload_to_testflight has some properties which should do the trick: changelog, beta_app_description. http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_testflight/#upload_to_testflight

Comment: Hi, when I'm trying to use Fastlane it required 2FA and I can't use it as part of my automatic pipeline. 
It is possible to change "Test Details" with apple rest API?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/#introduction for your options with 2FA in CI pipeline. Fastlane uses the app-store-connect api, so if the upload_to_testflight action is able to set it. You should be able to figure out how its done directly using the api.